# Double Tap is required to navigate from details view to list View

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

From the List view, the message details view is shown.

```
NavigationView() {
        List(msgData) { msg in
            NavigationLink(destination: MessageDetailsView(msgDetails :msg )) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5)
                        {
                            Text(msg.name).font(.system(size: 16)).fontWeight(.semibold).foregroundColor(.black)

                        }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Messages").font(.headline), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(false)
    }
```

Following is the message details view

```
 VStack
    {

        List {

            ForEach(chatMsgArray, id: \.self) { chat in
                ChatRow(chatMessage: chat)
            }

        }
    }
    .navigationBarItems(leading:
    Button(action: {
    print("Back button pressed...")
    }) {
    } , trailing:Button(action: {
    print("Call button pressed...")
    }) {
    }  )
```

I need to press the back button twice to go List View. Am getting below error while taping first time and it shows to list view on second tap.

> [TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its
>   visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy
>   (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a
>   window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to
>   load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view
>   bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and
>   will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout
>   passes. Make a symbolic breakpoint at
>   UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the
>   debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this
>   action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has
>   been added to a window. Table view:
>   <_TtC7SwiftUIP33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A4925UpdateCoalescingTableView:
>   0x107141800; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0; 375 667);
>   clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = ;
>   layer = ; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize:
>   {375, 483}; adjustedContentInset: {64, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource:
>   <_TtGC7SwiftUIP10$1c38d1a4819ListCoreCoordinatorGVS_20SystemListDataSourceOs5Never_GOS_19SelectionManagerBoxS2___:
>   0x106486780>>

Comment: It works fine if i remove the following line . .navigationBarItems(leading:
    Button(action: {
    print("Back button pressed...")
    }) {
    } , trailing:Button(action: {
    print("Call button pressed...")
    }) {
    }  )

Answer (score 0):

The following code fix this issue

@Environment(.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding

Then, in a button action or something, dismiss the view:
presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()